# The domain on IIS is overwriting the Subdirectory

Tags: django, laravel, iis, web-config, subdirectory

I have an site in IIS,  lets say **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** (*Laravel application*) , and i have my subdirectory **[www.example.com/subdirectory](http://www.example.com/subdirectory)** (*Django application*), when i access the **/subdirectory**, the domain overwrite my subdirectory and I get 404 page of Laravel,

I tried to make an rule in web.config of domain but i didn't get results, and I don't know what to

So, this is my configs in main.settings( Django)

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/subdirectory/'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/subdirectory/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/subdirectory/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL='/subdirectory/'
VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY = "subdirectory/"   
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com', 'localhost', 'wwww.example.com']
```

and my urlpatterns in main.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(f'{settings.VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY}admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('password_change/', views.password_change, name='password_change'),
    path(f'{settings.VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY}', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), 
    path(f'{settings.VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY}', views.index, name='index'),
    path(f'{settings.VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY}aluno/', include('aluno.urls')),
    path(f'{settings.VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY}empresa/', include('empresa.urls')),
]
```

and the web.config on Laravel

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
          <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
          <dynamicTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
          </dynamicTypes>
          <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="image/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
          </staticTypes>
        </httpCompression>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                
                
                <!-- INICIO - TO WWW  -->
                <rule name="Redirect to www" enabled="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <!-- FIM - TO WWW  -->
                
                <!-- INICIO - HTTP to HTTPS  -->
                <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <!-- FIM - HTTP to HTTPS -->                

                
                
                <!-- FIM - LINKS REDIRECIONAMENTOS  -->

                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>

                 <rule name="subdirectory" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^subdirectory(.*)" />
              <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="None" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
          </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" />
        </handlers>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
        <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
        <customErrors mode="Off" />     
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: show us your web.config file, your request does not reach Django as it is being routed to Laravel app by IIS. 
https://serverfault.com/questions/358505/iis7-main-site-with-subdirectories-that-are-also-sites

Comment: i added the web.config file @iklinac

Comment: It seems that the IIS Rewrite module doesn’t work. Have you installed the URL Rewrite extension in IIS? It is not enough yet to configure it in the webconfig file.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite